# How to use combinations in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to know the method combinations.

Actually, I have

Input:

```
sQmqgE sQmqgE sQmqgE sQmqgE JKOPDB JKOPDB JKOPDB YGJs YGJs YGJs ERLnA ERLnA ERLnA ERLnA ERLnA XPfQ hntJdN hntJdN hntJdN hntJdN hntJdN BPAdv BPAdv BPAdv BPAdv lTOF lTOF SPrVV SPrVV aavqj
```

My code :

```
test.flatMap{line => line.split(" ")}
            .flatMap{word => word.combinations(2)}
            .map{paire=>(paire.mkString(","),1)}
            .reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

Output :

```
(c,k,1981)
(e,e,1998)
(U,A,1970)
(h,f,1947)
(Y,Q,2133)
(o,s,2077)
(F,F,1965)
```

But I want the combinations words per words and not letter per letter.

--------------EDIT---------

Here we can see that my reducer always returns 1.
 For example the pairs (abc,mno) shouldn't return 1

```html
val myRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq("abc def ghi mno mno", "jkl mno pqr abc abc"))
myRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[7] at parallelize at <console>:27

scala> myRDD.foreach{println}
abc def ghi mno mno
jkl mno pqr abc abc

scala> myRDD.map(_.split(" ")).flatMap(_.combinations(2)).
     | map(p=>(p.mkString(","),1)).
     | reduceByKey(_+_).
     | foreach{println}
(jkl,abc,1)
(def,ghi,1)
(jkl,mno,1)
(abc,ghi,1)
(ghi,mno,1)
(mno,pqr,1)
(def,mno,1)
(abc,def,1)
(pqr,abc,1)
(abc,abc,1)
(abc,mno,1)
(mno,abc,1)
(jkl,pqr,1)
(mno,mno,1)
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Is all of your data on a single line? Do you want the combinations within each line or across lines?

Comment: No, I have around 20 words per line. I want the combinations within each line and my reducer will plot the combinations across all file.

Comment: Perfect, see my answer below

Comment: OP, please don't change the question after it has been answered. If you have a new question please open a new post

Comment: As for this specific problem, I addressed it in my comment to my answer below: sort the combinations before applying `mkString`

Comment: `(mno, abc)` and `(abc, mno)` are two different strings, why would you expect them to be grouped together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only want the combinations within each line you would do something like this:

```
scala> val myRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq("abc def ghi", "jkl mno pqr"))
myRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[1] at parallelize at <console>:24

scala> myRDD.foreach{println}
abc def ghi
jkl mno pqr

scala> myRDD.map(_.split(" ")).flatMap(_.combinations(2)).
     | map(p=>(p.mkString(","),1)).
     | reduceByKey(_+_).
     | foreach{println}
(abc,ghi,1)
(mno,pqr,1)
(abc,def,1)
(jkl,pqr,1)
(def,ghi,1)
(jkl,mno,1)
```

The problem with your code is that you are using a `flatMap` in the first line which gives a `RDD[String]` where the string is each word in your dataset:

```
scala> myRDD.flatMap(_.split(" "))
res0: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[19] at flatMap at <console>:27

scala> res0.foreach{println}
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
pqr
```

whereas in my version I use a `map` which does not flatten the split strings and gives a `RDD[Array[String]]`:

```
scala> myRDD.map(_.split(" "))
res1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[18] at map at <console>:27

scala> res1.foreach(l => println(l.mkString("::")))
abc::def::ghi
jkl::mno::pqr
```

Thus I am calling `combinations` on a list of words rather than a list of `Chars` (ie a string):

```
scala> List("abc", "def", "ghi").combinations(2).map(_.mkString("-")).toList
res2: List[String] = List(abc-def, abc-ghi, def-ghi)

scala> "abc".combinations(2).map(_.mkString("-")).toList
res3: List[String] = List(a-b, a-c, b-c)
```

Comment: It's work! Thank you! I have a last question my reducer always returns 1 and not the sum of all values.

Comment: They may all be unique combinations. Also you are keying on the combinations as a string which means that `(a,b)` will not match not match `(b,a)` (even though it should). If you sort the entries then you will have consistent pairs

Comment: If this has been helpful please [upvote and accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!